# Scala type bounds in builder

Tags: scala, types, type-bounds, bounded-types

I think I narrowed my problem down to the following:

```
trait Thing

case class SpecificThing(i: Int) extends Thing

trait ThingSource[T <: Thing] {
  def  next: T
}

class SpecificThingSource() extends ThingSource[SpecificThing] {
  override def next = SpecificThing(1)
}

object ThingSource {
  def apply[A <: Thing, B <: ThingSource[A]](sourceType: String): B = {
    sourceType match {
      case "specific" => new SpecificThingSource()
    }
  }
}

val a = ThingSource("specific").next
```

The compiler seems to be happy about most of it, except for the builder part. Here it gives this error:

```
Expression of type SpecificThingSource doesn't conform to the expected type B
```

I would expect that with `SpecificThing` being a subtype of type `Thing`, and `SpecificThingSource` being of type `ThingSource[SpecificThing]`, there is no room for ambiguity. What am I missing? Is it even possible to use a builder in this way? Or are there better ways to achieve what I want?

Comment: There is fundamentally no way to correctly implement a method with signature `def apply[A <: Thing, B <: ThingSource[A]](s: String): B`, because it guarantees to produce a value of type `Nothing` if I invoke it with `apply[AnyThingImpl, Nothing]("foobar")`. That cannot work. Please describe in more detail what exactly you tried to achieve.

Comment: I want ThingSource to instantiate and return a subclass of ThingSource, depending on the string passed into it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *"return **a** subclass of `ThingSource`"*, then you need *existential*, not *universal* quantification:

```
  def apply(sourceType: String)
  : B forSome { type B <: ThingSource[A] forSome { type A <: Thing}} = {
    sourceType match {
      case "specific" => new SpecificThingSource()
    }
  }
```

which can be written shorter as

```
  def apply(sourceType: String): ThingSource[_] = {
    sourceType match {
      case "specific" => new SpecificThingSource()
    }
  }
```